# How to bind 2nd function to the jQuery validation submitHandler

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

How would I add additional functionality to the jQuery validation submitHandler that is set in another script?  I cannot modify the source JavaScript that is defining the submitHandler in the first place.  Instead, I need to add some additional functionality to it from a subsequent script that runs.  Here is some scaled-down pseudo-code for the .js file that is defining the submitHandler in the first place--which I cannot directly modify:

```
$("#frmReg").validate({
    invalidHandler: function(e, validator) { //code here ... not relevant },
    submitHandler: function() {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
        $('#myForm')[0].submit();             
    },
    rules: { firstname: { required: true } },
    messages: { firstname: { required: 'First name is required' } }
});
```

Essentially, I want to bind a *second* function to the existing submitHander.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I glanced over the source and I think this should work:

```
var validatorInstance = $("#frmReg").validate(), //Call this AFTER the initial registration,
    submitHandler = validatorInstance.settings.submitHandler;

validatorInstance.settings.submitHandler = function(){
    //Do your custom stuff here
    console.log(true);
    return submitHandler.apply(this,arguments); //forward to the old handler
};
```

Comment: This looks promising.  I'm playing with it...so far after the custom stuff and the console log message, it is logging this error and submitting the form without running the pre-existing handler function : submitHandler is undefined

Comment: @Shawn can you provide a jsfiddle. Are you using the latest version? It's based on this source code: http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js

Comment: Looks like the page is using jquery.validate-1.8.1.min.js.  I'll see about adding a jsfiddle.

Comment: @Shawn 1.8.1 should be the same in this regard after looking at its code.. are you sure you're calling `var validatorInstance = $("#frmReg").validate()` after the first `.validate()`? what does `console.log(validatorInstance)` give?